# What's the name of that 80s or 90s sci-fi movie where they have to save a princess from a huge spider?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

What's the name of that sci-fi movie from the 80s or early 90s where they have to save a princess from a huge spider?

The spider kept the princess trapped in some room in her web or something.

There was a cyclops type creature that died squished in between some doors when he was holding the door open for his friend.

It was a group of people, and at the end of the movie the evil mountain or whatever exploded as they were riding away from it.

Anyone know?

Comment: __[Krull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_(film))__ (1983) immediately comes to mind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Krull](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085811/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

You can watch the complete movie here:

At the end you can see the mountain exploding (the sequence starts ca. at the 1:50:20 mark). Ca. at the 1:08:50 mark starts the spider's lair part, and ca. at the 1:12:10 mark you can have the first glimpse at the huge white spider. And ca. at the 1:32:20 mark you can see the one-eyed cyclops type dude.

[On this Krull Wiki site](http://krull.wikia.com/wiki/Crystal_Spider) there are pictures of the giant Crystal Spider.

And here is [Rell, the Cyclops](http://krull.wikia.com/wiki/Rell).

Comment: Note that the princess was not at all held captive by the spider, but after all this time it's no wonder some details would be confused.

Comment: Thank you Casspir!! @Todd Wilcox Yup, it's been a while!